# Cannot upgrade pyspark from 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In my machine, `pyspark 2.2.0` is installed. I checked the spark official website, it looks if I want to install `2.3.0`, all I need to do is `pip install pyspark`. But what I get is:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyspark in 
/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: py4j==0.10.4 in 
/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyspark)
$ pip freeze | grep pyspark
pyspark==2.2.0
```

So my pyspark is not upgraded. How can I upgrade the pyspark? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use upgrade option:

```
pip install --upgrade pyspark
```